# Can't run executable from external hard drive, it says I need permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have this seemingly simple problem and I can't figure out how to solve.

I have a small exe I created myself and I would like to run it directly from an USB drive or external HD.

I can use it if I copy it onto a local directory, but this issue has left me stumped, I would like to run it directly without having to copy it around :)

The error that pops up states that Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file and that I may not have the required permissions. (I am the administrator, also running the exe as administrator renders the same error)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible that the *exe* is requiring libraries using a relative path instead of an absolute path?

Comment: It is as simple as putting the executable on the external drive and running it.  What file can the application not access specifically?

Comment: That could be the problem, it's a C# program, so it could be accessing some .NET library, but those reside on the computer, and are accessible to anyone, I think.

Comment: troubleshoot. Create a file named blah.exe and run it and see if you get the same error. Try other EXE files.  Quote the error message's exact words, because googling it requires the exact wording. And then you can also try to improve your terribly useless title.

Comment: In addition to barlop's suggestion (try other EXE files), try finding out: What permissions are specified on the directory?  (It could specify that user doesn't have Execute permissions.)  I see barlop already adjusted the previous title that he was commenting on.

Comment: I cannot open any .exe file, the same error pops up. I have full control permission on the directory. I also tried turning off antivirus and firewall, still displays "Windows cannot access device, path or specified file. You may not have adequate permissions to access this item."

Answer (score 0):

I have found why I could not open any .exe files, there was an Antivirus restriction that remained active even after turning off active protection on removable devices.